# How to pass a function from view.py to html

Tags: python, django

## views.py

```
def detect_full_text(tweet):
if 'retweeted_status' in tweet.*_json*:
    analysis_tweet =  tweet._json['retweeted_status']['full_text']
else:
    analysis_tweet = tweet.full_text
return (analysis_tweet)
```

## public_tweet.html

{% for analyze in analysis %}

```
  <tr>  

    <td>  
      {{ detect_full_text(analyze) }}

    </td>
    <td>  
      {{ analyze.created_at }} 
    </td>
    <td>  
      {{ analyze.favorite_count }} 
    </td>
    <td>  
      {{ analyze.retweet_count }} 
    </td>


  </tr>

  {% endfor %}
```

I want to call python function from view.py in the html page